# Diagonalization with a matrix in $SL_n(\mathbb{R})$

Tags: matrices, diagonalization

Suppose that $A$ is diagonalizable. Can the diagonalization be done with a matrix $P$ in the special linear group $SL_n(\mathbb{R})$ (i.e. such that $\det(P)=1$) ?

Comment: Sometimes. Are you looking for criteria when that is possible?

Comment: If $n$ is odd, you can always multiply the diagonalization by $-1$!

Comment: @DanielFischer Yes I am looking for criteria when that is possible.

Comment: Duh, I read $SL_n(\mathbb{Z})$, that would have been only sometimes possible. With $SL_n(\mathbb{R})$ there's no problem.

Answer (score 1):

It is always possible.

Suppose $U^{-1} A U = \Lambda$.

Let $P:\mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}^n$ be given by $P((x_1,...,x_n)) = (\frac{x_1}{\det U},x_2,...,x_n))$. Then $\det P = \frac{1}{\det U}$.

Then $(UP)^{-1} A (UP) = \Lambda$, and $\det (U P) = 1$.

Answer (score 0):

Yes.

If A is diagonalized with $Q$, just multiply one column of $Q$ by $\frac{1}{\det(Q)}$ to get $P$.